# Mascara de horas HH:MM a partir de um campo tipo number usando oracle sql para usar em relatorio

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, pl-sql

Tenho uma query que uso para fazer um relatório de horas trabalhadas, tentei usar o to_char e alguns outros exemplos que encontrei no stackoverflow.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN BC.ENTRADA1 IS NULL
        THEN 0
        ELSE REGEXP_REPLACE(lpad(to_char(BC.ENTRADA1),4,'0'), '([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})', '\1:\2')
        END  AS "Ent1"
FROM BCOEXT BC
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

*ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava NUMBER obteve CHAR
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"*

Estou utilizando o OracleSQL e o SQL developer, agradeço quem puder ajudar

Se existir outra forma de fazer essa máscara será de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 2):

Se tem um campo número, por exemplo 1522 seria "15:22", pode fazer convertendo o número para string com `TO_CHAR` e usar `SUBSTR` para pegar os digitos da hora e dos minutos, assim:

```
substr(to_char(BC.ENTRADA1),1,2) ||':'|| substr(to_char(BC.ENTRADA1),3,2)
```

Basicamente:

- converte para char
- pega os dois primeiros digitos (`subtr(...,1,2)`)
- concatena com ":"
- pega os dois últimos digitos,(`subtr(...,3,2)`)

Veja aqui funcionando: [http://sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ab5e1d/34)